# What's the difference between figure and drawing in patent grant?

Tags: uspto, patent-drawings, patent-figures

USPTO patent grant bulk-data contains two fields number-of-figures and number-of-drawings.  Figures number is always higher or same. So, I guess that drawings is a sub-set of figures.

I have looked on the [UPSTO information page](https://mpep.uspto.gov/RDMS/MPEP/e8r9#/e8r9/d0e47639.html), but there is no clear distinction between figures and drawings mentioned. In fact they seem to use the terms interchangeably in some places.

So, I'm curios what is technical difference between figure and drawing?

Comment: I do not know what the bilk data labels are it would make sense if drawings were number of drawing sheets. "Drawings" is used informally but the correct name for the figures is a figure.

Answer (score 1):

The figures are called figures. A label called "drawings" might be the number of drawing sheets, which would be less than or equal to the number of figures.

Comment: What is a "drawing sheet"?

Comment: a letter size or A4 size paper with one or more figures on it.